# ASP.NET User control performance enhancement

Tags: asp.net, performance, caching, asynchronous, user-controls

I have a ASP.NET user control... comprising of a bunch of business-workflow-defined radio buttons.
Depending on the intial set of options chosen:
1) More radio button options load as a part of a tree control
2) Depending on option chosen -  in turn loads one of the 5 other ASP.NET usercontrols dynamically.
There are postbacks  and page reloads in between these transitions.

What options for performance enhancement can be applied to this legacy code?

Comment: Are you fetching data from database for User controls has to be loaded dynamically?

Comment: We would need to see some of the code to offer an educated answer. Whether caching is an option depends on the data. If you're not already, loading the nodes on-demand might improve performance.

Comment: Where is it actually hurting the performance? time taken to hit DB is more? frequent postbacks? Lot of service calls?

Answer (score 0):

Using ASP.NET Ajax may help if there are some parts of the page that need to interact with the server frequently. However, in my experience, ASP.NET Ajax doesn't live up to the promise of Ajax in terms of low latency interactions because of the ViewState bloat that accompanies all ASP.NET pages of any reasonable complexity.

I've found Scott Mitchell's article on [Persisting Page State](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131036/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011707-1.aspx) to be a very good resource for ideas for getting away from massive ViewState in ASP.NET web forms. I've used his FileSystemPageStatePersister with good results on production systems, however, the approach is incompatible with ASP.NET Ajax, and may not scale well to a web farm.